# Vertical List Within a Horizontal List

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a basic navigation and I'd like to have a horizontal list with a vertical items list:

```
Header 1     Header 2     Header 3
 -Sub 1       -Sub 1       -Sub 1
 -Sub 2       -Sub 2       -Sub 2
 -Sub 3       -Sub 3       -Sub 3
```

I'm shooting for this markup, or something similar:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>Header 1</strong>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><strong>Header 2</strong>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><strong>Header 3</strong>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I'm trying to avoid floating divs for each header section.

I've been trying to use two css classes for the uls, with the outer set to `display:inline` and the inner to `display:block`, but I can't get it to work.

How do I do this, or do I have to float divs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can float the first-level `li`s (to avoid 'floating divs'), or use `display: inline-block` for the first-level `li`s. Bearing in mind that floating will work for IE6+, whereas `inline-block` is restricted to only those elements that would normally display `inline`.

Basic demo for the first (float the first-level `li`s) suggestion:

```css
 ul {
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 ul > li {
   float: left;
   width: 32%;
 }
 ul > li > ul {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
 }
 ul > li > ul > li {
   display: block;
   float: none;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><strong>Header 1</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><strong>Header 2</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><strong>Header 3</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Basic demo for the second (`display: inline-block` for the first-level `li`s) suggestion:

```css
ul {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
}
ul li ul {
  width: 100%;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><strong>Header 1</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><strong>Header 2</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><strong>Header 3</strong>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="1">Abcdefghi</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="2">Jklmnopqr</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="3">stuvwzyz</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: +1 Yep, that's what I would've said.  Although, I think it would be helpful if you include the relevant CSS as part of your answer.  What if JSBin folds?

Comment: @Josh, I posted and wandered off, basically; and for some reason I thought I *had* included the css. Ah, the senility of my middle age... =)

Comment: THanks.  I thought I wrote a comment like 6 hours ago, but apparently not.  This worked perfectly.  I wasn't using the > selector correctly.  Don't know what I was thinking.  THanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try below code i spent a litle time for anyone needs this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
   .ul  li {
  float: left;
  width:30%;
}

.ul>li ul{
   display:block;
   margin-left:-30px;
}

.ul>li ul>li{
   display:block;
   float:none;
}
.ul>li a{
    color:white;
}

footer {
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background: #333;
    color:white;
}

</style>

<footer>
<div>
<ul class="ul">
   <li>
       naber

         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link bir</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link bir</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link bir</a></li>
         </ul>

   </li>
   <li>
       dostum

         <ul>
            <li>birrr</li>
            <li>iki</li>
            <li>uc</li>
         </ul>

   </li>
   <li>
       nasılsın

         <ul>
            <li>bir</li>
            <li>iki</li>
            <li>uc</li>
         </ul>

   </li>
</ul>
</div>

</footer>

</body>
</html>
```